# Android TTS: Speaking Long text

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

Is there any way we can speak a text which is greater than `getMaxSpeechInputLength()` using Android TTS? Currently I am speaking the text by breaking it into pieces and putting them into an array, but that is not the best way, there are delays.

Any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using synthesizeToFile method and playing audio in MediaPlayer. I think, it's the simplest way